# Helm deployment status if tests failed

Tags: testing, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Is it possible to make Helm charts deployment to fail if test which is run before installation fails? Because now despite the test fails, status is 'Deployed'.

My test, which checks if MongoDB is deployed and is reachable:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: "{{ .Release.Name }}-database-connection-test"
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook": pre-install,test-success
    "helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": before-hook-creation
spec:
  containers:
  - name: {{ .Release.Name }}-database-connection-test
    image: {{ template "mongo.image" . }}
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    env:
      - name: HOST
        value: {{ .Values.mongo.host }}
      - name: PORT
        value: {{ .Values.mongo.port | quote }}
      - name: DATABASE_NAME
        value: {{ .Values.mongo.databasename }}
      - name: USERNAME
        value: {{ .Values.mongo.username }}
      - name: PASSWORD
        value: {{ .Values.mongo.password }}
    command: ["sh", "-c", "mongo --username $USERNAME --password $PASSWORD --authenticationDatabase $DATABASE_NAME --host $HOST --port $PORT"]
  restartPolicy: Never
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in general this can be achieved setting resource type as `Job`.
Job will be blocking Tiller until it will complete. 
There is a small issue here: if job will not complete it will be blocking Helm chart deployment infinite amount of time. To avoid that, need to set `spec.activeDeadlineSeconds`. It will timeout the job if it will not complete until the set time limit.

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: "{{ .Release.Name }}-database-connection-test"
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook": pre-install,test-success
    "helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": before-hook-creation
spec:
  ttlSecondsAfterFinished: 300
  backoffPolicy: 1
  activeDeadlineSeconds: 100
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: {{ .Release.Name }}-database-connection-test
        image: {{ template "mongo.image" . }}
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        env:
          - name: HOST
            value: {{ .Values.mongo.host }}
          - name: PORT
            value: {{ .Values.mongo.port | quote }}
          - name: DATABASE_NAME
            value: {{ .Values.mongo.databasename }}
          - name: USERNAME
            value: {{ .Values.mongo.username }}
          - name: PASSWORD
            value: {{ .Values.mongo.password }}
        command: ["sh", "-c", "mongo --username $USERNAME --password $PASSWORD --authenticationDatabase $DATABASE_NAME --host $HOST --port $PORT"]
      restartPolicy: Never
```

It's kind of a workaround, because initially Helm test annotation shouldn't be used alongside other hooks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best solution here would be to separate both hooks (pre-install and test) as Remigijus also suggested.

- "**pre-install**" hook would run before any K8s resources defined under chart/templates directory are created using "**helm install/upgrade**" command.
- "**test**" hook would run when "**helm test**" command is executed.

Note: Helm-3 supports single test hook named "test". "test-success", etc are deprecated.